# Custom Image Picker/ UIScrollView not appearing in view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

New developer here,Im using the Custom Image Picker by ray wenderlich. But what I wanted to do is show the picker not by pressing a button but when the view loads. I can't seem to make it appear. Here is what I have done, I dont know what seems to be wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(120, 120)]];
}

- (void) createScrollView {
    UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,200.0f)];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*140+24, row*150+10, 100, 100);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [view addSubview:button];

        if (column == 6) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, (row+1) * 150 + 10)];
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self createScrollView];
    _images =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _thumbs =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.png", i]]; 
        NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [_images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

            NSLog(@"file exists");
        } 
        NSLog(@"file does not exist");
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating scroll view first and then initialising image array, due to which it won't appear.

Rather Use like -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_images =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_thumbs =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.png", i]]; 
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        [_images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

        NSLog(@"file exists");
    } 
    NSLog(@"file does not exist");
}

[self createScrollView];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: have tried it but still doesn display anything. btw, I'm using it for iPad.

Comment: have you tried debugging, what is value in array when method createScrollView is called?

Comment: the scrollview is displayed but the images are not.

Comment: That is what the issue is, now you need to debug for loop of viewDidLoad? And see what is happening there. may be it is not finding the proper path?

Comment: I don't know how. So now the count was right. But it doesn't display.

Comment: Check this, and you will be able to use debugger to analyse what is actually happening inside your code - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Answer (score 3):

1st add the button in scrollview and at the last after for loop add the scrolview in self.view.

```
- (void) createScrollView {
    UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,200.0f)];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*140+24, row*150+10, 100, 100);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [view addSubview:button];

        if (column == 6) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }

    [view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, (row+1) * 150 + 10)];

  [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

i hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the commented lines

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
```

You should do anything after the `[super viewDidLoad];` is called.

Secondly, in your `createScrollView` method, you are adding the scrollview to `self.view` `_thumbs.count` times(think you are using only one scrollview, if so adding one time is enough).

So put the piece of code

```
 [self.view addSubview:view];
```

above the for loop.

Also do as per rishi's answer.

Hope this helps you.